# Create IQueryable extension method without predicate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After searching in a lot of places, I ended up asking for your help.

The problem is this: I need to create a filter using IQueryable but without a predicate. Say for example I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass: IQueryable
{
     public string P1 {get; set;}
     public string P2 {get; set;}
}
```

Now I need a filter for this class or any other class for that matter where I can call it for example like this:

```
  var ex1 = MyClass.MyFilter<P1>;
```

Instead of

```
  var ex = someCollection.Where( p => p.SomeProperty == P1 );
```

Something like this is being used by Kendo Grids in ASP.NET when binding properties or classes to grids and columns. Any idea or advice is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit unsure on what you are trying to do, but is it something along the lines of:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string P1 { get; set; }
    }

    public static class QueryableExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> MyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string value) where T : MyClass
        {
            return queryable.Where(arg => arg.P1 == value);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Hello janhartmann! Yes, something in the neighborhood of! Also I am trying to get rid of the lambda in the return statement, and I am trying to do it using a generic declaration, something that will work for each class.

Comment: I would suggest you introduce an interface and use it instead of MyClass. Then make your other classes implement the interface which contain the property.

Comment: An interface or an abstract class, whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you janhartmann, working on it right now. I think the final state will be a combination of the 2 answers above using reflection for SomeProperty.

Comment: I would recommend having a shared abstract class or interface on the required classes and ditch the reflection.

Answer (score 0):

IQueryable is just a datatype like any other, so you can make an extension function which accepts and returns objects of that type.

```
  public static class QueryExtensions
  {
      public IQueryable<MyClass> MyFilter(this IQueryable<MyClass> query, string p1)
      {
          return query.Where(p => p.SomeProperty == p1);
      }
  }
```

And to use it:

```
  var ex1 = someCollection.MyFilter(P1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer buffjape! Just another question: is there any way to avoid the predicate expression even inside the function itself? I want to be able to use this filter in DB queries from EF or nHibernate as well. Thank you !

Comment: That works pretty well buffjape! Thank you ! Also is there any way to put SomeProperty into a variable as well ?

Comment: To [pass SomeProperty in, use a lambda expression - the predicate you are trying to get rid of (but there's no reason to get rid of it really).